# Django: How to query terms with punctuation (ie: !.;’) insensitivity?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an application that needs to find facebook usernames that I’ve stored in the database, but facebook usernames are both case insensitive and insensitive to periods. For example, the username Johnsmith.55 is the same as johnsmith55 or even j…O.hn.sMiTh.5.5. when sending facebook API requests.
Obviously, I am using the _iexact query command to remedy the case insensitivity, but what can I use to remedy the insensitivity to periods? I know a cop out method is simply to save all usernames to the database after stripping them of periods and also stripping the username that’s being searched of its periods and then querying, but I want to save and display people’s username’s the way that they really appear in their facebook URL (which includes periods) even though facebook API requests technically are insensitive to periods.

Any ideas for a simple method of doing this? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store two user names in your DB, one to query against and one to display.

However, if you don't want to have to do that, it's simple matter of cleaning the string from the characters Facebook ignores before querying:

```
# ... import 're' and pull username from DB
normalized_username = re.sub('[,.]', '', real_username)
# query using the normalized username
```

**Note:** This example ignores dots and commas, Facebook may ignore more than that.

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what Daniel has said above. I think this appears to be the only way. I will implement this way since there is no other option. I was hoping there was a way that did not need to involve 2x the storage space for usernames in the db, but it appears there is not.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store two versions of the username: one for querying against, and one for display.

Comment: Ah, so there really is no django querying function that I'm missing here then? That's fine. So the best way to do it would be to add a facebook_username_query element to my facebookinfo object and strip this of all periods and caps then and then only query against that? It sounds like it is going to cost an unnecessary amount of memory database storage, but if there really is no other way, then I guess I have no choice.

Comment: Seriously, storage is cheap. It's just one more column per row. Storage should be the least of your concerns here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also implement your own querying loguc with custom lookups in Django 1.7 or later.